# Why does IntelliJ IDEA say "Cannot resolve symbol spark" for spark.sparkContext.textFile?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

The follow is my pom.xml

```
<groupId>recommend</groupId>
<artifactId>MovieLensALS</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    <spark.version>2.1.1</spark.version>
    <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image: wrong code hint]

I want use Spark Sql int  Intellij but some thing is wrong. My Spark version is the latest 2.1.1 and scala version is 2.11.*
Who can tell me what is problem or tell me how to code about spark sql(2.1.1)

Answer (score 3):

You have to create an instance of `SparkSession` that you call `spark`.

Quoting [Starting Point: SparkSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession):

> The entry point into all functionality in Spark is the `SparkSession` class. To create a basic `SparkSession`, just use `SparkSession.builder()`

Quoting the [scaladoc of SparkSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession):

> The builder can also be used to create a new session:
>
> ```
> SparkSession.builder()
>   .master("local")
>   .appName("Word Count")
>   .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
>   .getOrCreate()
> ```

**Protip** Don't use `spark.sparkContext` for anything in Spark SQL. Use [SparkSession.read](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@read:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) instead.